# OnClIck in Javascript Not Working For Image

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have OnClick Function and On ClientClick Function as

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnSchedule" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ImageUrl="~/images/Update2.png" ToolTip="Refresh"  OnClick="imgbtnSchedule_Click"   OnClientClick="return validateUpdate(1);"  />
```

My OnClick Function Is Not Working so I Started Debugging using F12. but Here I can see my OnClick function Is Not there and Onclientclick property is showing as OnClick.

[image]

Comment: `OnClientClick` is turned into `onclick`. `onclick` is run on the server, not the client.

Comment: I have Onlick Function On Server side and An OnClientClick Function On client side,I am expecting Ececution Of both OnClick and OnClientClick,How To Achive this.

Comment: I don't use ASP.NET, but my guess is it does it with `addEventListener()` instead of an inline attribute.

Answer (score 0):

> I have Onlick Function On Server side and An OnClientClick Function On
> client side,I am expecting Ececution Of both OnClick and
> OnClientClick,How To Achive this

base on that code

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnSchedule" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ImageUrl="~/images/Update2.png" ToolTip="Refresh"  
    OnClick="imgbtnSchedule_Click"   
    OnClientClick="return validateUpdate(1);"  />
```

If the `validateUpdate(1)` **returns false**, then the `imgbtnSchedule_Click` will not called.

Comment: return true; I have Added Return true,and its executing Till return true.But On Debugging(F12) I can see My OnClientClick Has Turned Into OnClick And My actual OnClick Is not There .The Image Attached In Above Question And My Code are Different for OnClick And OnClientClick.

Comment: @ashish_anand_93 this is the way - the one is used to call the code behind, the other the javascript - and they change name